# ordenar numero de una array sin funciones en java

Tags: java, array

quiero ordenar los numeros de una array de menor a mayor pero sin usar una funcion como puede ser sort.
No se como hacerlo y de momento llevo este codigo, pero no se como continuar, si alguien me puede ayudar se lo agradeceria.

```
public class ordenarArray{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int numeros []={6,1,7,9,10,1};
        int mayor=0;
        for (int i = 0; i<numeros.length;i++){
            if (numeros[i] > mayor){
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

PD:Tambien necesito hacerlo sin crear un array auxiliar

Comment: con 2 ciclos for lo solucionarías

Comment: Con un for dentro de otro? y luego como saco el numero que me interesa para poder ponerlo primero en la lista?

Comment: Me puedes decir como quedaria el codigo pq no estoy seguro de a que te refieres

Comment: Asi? for (int i = 0; i<numeros.length;i++){
            for (int x = 0; x<numeros.length;x++){
                
        }
    }

Comment: Ahí hay 5 formas de ordenamiento junto con su código en java

https://favtutor.com/blogs/sorting-algorithms-java

Bubble sort e Insertion sort son mejores con arreglos pequeños, con arreglos grandes son mejores Merge sort y Heap sort

Answer (score 2, accepted):

como te comentaba el compañero, la solucion la encuentras con dos bucles for anidados. Se me ocurre la siguiente solucion:

```
int[] array = {6,1,7,9,10,1};
int temp;

for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < array.length - 1 - i; j++) {
        if (array[j] > array[j + 1]) {
            temp = array[j];
            array[j] = array[j + 1];
            array[j + 1] = temp;
        }
    }
}

// Imprimir el array ordenado
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    System.out.print(array[i] + " ");
}
```

Lo importante esta dentro del if. Si el numero seleccionado es mayor que el siguiente correra el if y dentro de este, igualara el entero `temp` a ese numero, el numero pasara a ser el de la siguiente posicion y el de la siguiente posicion sera el entero anteriormente guardado en `temp`.

La razon por la cual uso `j < array.length - 1 - i;` en la condicion del segundo for es para reducir la cantidad de comparaciones que se deben realizar en cada iteración. Cada vez que se realiza una iteración del ciclo externo (el cual recorre el array de principio a fin, osea el primer bucle), se "hace flotar" el elemento más grande hacia el final del array. Una vez que este elemento se ha "flotado", ya no es necesario compararlo con los demás elementos, por lo que se puede excluirlo de las comparaciones en las iteraciones siguientes.

---

Entiendo que esto sera un ejercicio de clase con pocos numeros pero ten en cuenta que para arrays de gran tamaño, esto no seria lo mas optimo.

Un saludo, espero haberte ayudado!!

Comment: Perfecto muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Sin usar un array auxiliar, puedes modificar el mismo array `numeros` con 2 ciclos `for`, en donde el primer `for` recorre todo el array y el segundo `for` busca el elemento más pequeño (por el `if`), en donde éste irá primero en el array:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++){
    int aux = i;
    for (int j = i + 1; j < numeros.length; j++) {
        if (numeros[j] < numeros[aux]) {
            aux = j;
        }
    }
    // aquí modifico el array, dependiendo qué sea "aux" en cada ciclo.
    int temp = numeros[aux];
    numeros[aux] = numeros[i];
    numeros[i] = temp;
}
```

Luego tendrías que recorrer el mismo array para ver el resultado (con los elementos ya ordenados):

```
for (int i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++){
    System.out.print(numeros[i] + " ");
}
```

---

Código completo:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int numeros []={6,1,7,9,10,1};

    for (int i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++){
        int aux = i;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < numeros.length; j++) {
            if (numeros[j] < numeros[aux]) {
                aux = j;
            }
        }
        // aquí modifico el array, dependiendo qué sea "aux" en cada ciclo.
        int temp = numeros[aux];
        numeros[aux] = numeros[i];
        numeros[i] = temp;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++){
        System.out.print(numeros[i]+ " ");
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
// 1 1 6 7 9 10
```

Comment: MUchas gracias por tu codigo